# webkitdirectory file upload is not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

`<input type="file" accept="..." directory="" mozdirectory="" webkitdirectory="" id="file-upload-btn" onchange="btnImportProjectClick(event)" multiple="">`

i am using this file upload to upload whole directory. it's working fine on mac or window laptop for all browsers. but on mobile ios, tablet ios and android tablet it's not working proper. It's not picking whole directory. giving only multiple file upload option instead of directory. I am using simple VanilaJs for my webapp. please let me know if anybody have any solution of the problem.

i tried
`<input type="file" directory="" mozdirectory="" webkitdirectory="" id="file-upload-btn" onchange="btnImportProjectClick(event)" multiple="">`

tried this also

`<input type="file" directory mozdirectory webkitdirectory id="file-upload-btn" onchange="btnImportProjectClick(event)" multiple="">`

tried this too

`<input type="file" directory webkitdirectory id="file-upload-btn" onchange="btnImportProjectClick(event)" multiple="">`

and

`<input type="file" webkitdirectory id="file-upload-btn" onchange="btnImportProjectClick(event)" multiple="">`

Comment: Not available on mobile browsers - https://caniuse.com/input-file-directory